# SQL, T-SQL look up

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
RegistryNo  DateOfDiagnosis ExtentOfDisease Laterality  HospitalFacility
1234        1/07/2006       DCIS            L           L-556
1234        1/12/2006       Invasive        L           L-556
2342        1/05/2004       DCIS            R           A-448
3565        1/06/2006       DCIS            L           L-556
3565        1/05/2005       DCIS            R           L-556
5678        1/09/2000       Invasive        L           L-556
6689        1/10/2001       DCIS            L           A-448
6689        1/01/1999       Invasive        R           A-448
```

How would you manipulate the dataset into the following form:

A dataset containing one record for each case of DCIS, with a binary flag (yes/no) indicating whether the woman progressed from DCIS to invasive disease and time to progression to invasive disease if applicable?

Note to be classified as “progressed” a cancer should first be classified as DCIS and then later as Invasive in the same breast (i.e. same laterality).

Comment: Will be really good if you add sample of desired result

Answer (score 2):

Try this (change "yourtable" with your actual table name:

```
select 
    tbl_dcis.RegistryNo,
    case when tbl_inv.RegistryNo is null then 0 else 1 end as progressed_to_invasive,
    case when tbl_inv.RegistryNo is null then null else tbl_inv.DateOfDiagnosis - tbl_dcis.DateOfDiagnosis as difference_in_days
from yourtable as tbl_dcis
left join yourtable as tbl_inv on tbl_dcis.RegistryNo=tbl_inv.RegistryNo
where 
    tbl_dcis.ExtentOfDisease='DCIS'
    and tbl_inv.ExtentOfDisease='Invasive'
    and tbl_dcis.DateOfDiagnosis <= tbl_inv.DateOfDiagnosis
```